# Using one central .xlsx shared file to store data

Tags: excel, vba

I have an .xlsm file which has user forms for data entry. Also has sheets that read data from a spreadsheet by way of formulas. All of the data is on 1 sheet which is currently in the same workbook, however I would like to constantly update from and back up to an .xlsx file which would only have the 1 worksheet containing data.

Comment: "update from" and "back up to" seem to be contradictory ?

Comment: Sounds more like a job for access than excel

Comment: If it is a single user then sure you can do it. But for multi user, you can use a shared file but that is not recommended. Like @Marcucciboy2 mentioned, this is more like a job for access. If you still want to use Excel, then use Excel as a frontend and save/read the data from Access Database.

Comment: If you dont have Access to make a database, then you can get SQL Server Express, which is free (as long as you dont need a HUGE database) and it's actually better than Access.